# MYSQL database collation latin1 swedish ci

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database which has collation latin1 swedish ci.
when i get data,  my PHP table show  �����
i don't want to change the collation in database.

How I can do this in my php code in order to get the data in right format.

Thanks

Comment: It is not php. I guess that is html page that output that

Comment: yes you are right, it is  html page.  any idea how to fix this issue?  i am new in programming and i need help...

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: i will try this but does not work. i have the same output.

Comment: so you *will* or you *did* ? Do you have public link to your page?

Comment: i did but does not work! no i have not public link.

Comment: please share your code. and db table definitions